# Read from a text file and use each line to compare if they are anagrams

Tags: c

I must modify my program to accept input from
a file called anagrams.txt.This file should have two strings per line, separated by the # character. My program should read
each pair of strings and report back if each pair of strings is an anagram. For example consider the following content of anagrams.txt:

**hello#elloh

man#nam

Astro#Oastrrasd**

Your program should print out the following:

**hello#elloh - Anagrams!**

**man#nam - Anagrams!**

**Astro#Oastrrasd- Not anagrams!**

**I should compile in g++**

Here is the code to read from text:

```
int main()
{
    char input[30];




      if(access( "anagrams.txt", F_OK ) != -1)           {

            FILE *ptr_file;
        char buf[1000];

        ptr_file =fopen("anagrams.txt","r");     if (!ptr_file)
            return 1;

        while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
            printf("%s",buf);

    fclose(ptr_file);
        printf("\n");
      }

      else{ //if file does not exist
        printf("\nFile not found!\n");
      }


        return 0;
}
```

Code to find if the text are anagrams:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int find_anagram(char [], char []);

int main()
{
    char array1[100], array2[100];
    int flag;

    printf("Enter the string\n");
    gets(array1);
    printf("Enter another string\n");
    gets(array2);
    flag = find_anagram(array1, array2);
    if (flag == 1)
        printf(" %s and %s are anagrams.\n", array1, array2);
    else
        printf("%s and %s are not anagrams.\n", array1, array2);
    return 0;
}

int find_anagram(char array1[], char array2[])
{
    int num1[26] = {0}, num2[26] = {0}, i = 0;

    while (array1[i] != '\0')
    {
        num1[array1[i] - 'a']++;
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (array2[i] != '\0')
    {
        num2[array2[i] -'a']++;
        i++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (num1[i] != num2[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The code you write is pure `C`. Don't mistag questions just because. `C` & `C++` are different languages in more than just name.

Comment: Also consider formatting your code better it is very difficult to read when it is this messy.

Comment: It's c, you guys understood what I am asking or you need some more help?

Comment: You are asking how to link up the above code using files?

Comment: Yes actually the code is there in separate files, I just want to mix them to make it work. I have a text file and I want to use each line in the text to check if they are anagrams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
#define MAXLETTER 256

int is_anagram(char *word1, char *word2);
void check_lines(FILE *filename);
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b);
void convert_to_lowercase(char *word);

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    FILE *filename;

    if ((filename = fopen("anagram.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    check_lines(filename);

    fclose(filename);

    return 0;
}

void
check_lines(FILE *filename) {
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char *word1, *word2, *copy1, *copy2;

    while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, filename) != NULL) {
        word1 = strtok(line, "#");
        word2 = strtok(NULL, "\n");

        copy1 = strdup(word1);
        copy2 = strdup(word2);

        convert_to_lowercase(copy1);
        convert_to_lowercase(copy2);

        if (is_anagram(copy1, copy2)) {
            printf("%s#%s - Anagrams!\n", word1, word2);
        } else {
            printf("%s#%s - Not Anagrams!\n", word1, word2);
        }
    }
}

void
convert_to_lowercase(char *word) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
}

int
is_anagram(char *word1, char *word2) {

    qsort(word1, strlen(word1), sizeof(*word1), cmpfunc);
    qsort(word2, strlen(word2), sizeof(*word2), cmpfunc);

    if (strcmp(word1, word2) == 0) {
        return 1;
    } 
    return 0;
}

int
cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    if ((*(char*)a) < (*(char*)b)) {
        return -1;
    }

    if ((*(char*)a) > (*(char*)b)) {
        return +1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you rock! Thanks a lot

Comment: No worries @Eternal. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: One note,  the code should not distinguish between capitals and lower-case letters. For example Man#nam is an anagram, how can I change it?

Comment: I updated the above code to fix this issue. I added a `convert_to_lowercase(char *word)` function which converts the words to all lower case beforehand, and then everything is treated equally.

Comment: did that help @Eternal, this method seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like a University question, I won't provide a full solution, only a hint.

All you have to do is replace the `stdin` input part of the anagram-finding file with the code you wrote to read from a file: it's as simple as changing

```
printf("Enter the string\n");
gets(array1);
printf("Enter another string\n");
gets(array2);
```

to
    // before program:
    #define SIZE 1000

```
// inside main

if (access("anagrams.txt", F_OK) == -1){
    printf("\nFile not found!\n");
    return 1; // Abort the program early if we can't find the file
}
FILE *ptr_file;
char buf[1000];

ptr_file = fopen("anagrams.txt","r");
if (!ptr_file)
    return 1;

char array1[SIZE], array2[SIZE];

while (fgets(buf, 1000, ptr_file)!=NULL){
    // do all your anagram stuff here!
    // there is currently one line of the input file stored in buf

    // Hint: You need to split buf into array_1 and array_2 using '#' to separate it.

}


fclose(ptr_file);
printf("\n");
```

Additional comments:

1. Don't **ever ever ever** use `gets`. `gets` doesn't check that the string it writes to can hold the data, which will cause your program to crash if it gets input bigger than the array size. Use `fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, stdin)` instead.
2. Beautiful code is good code. People are more likely to help if they can read your code easily. (fix your brackets)
3. Just for interest, a more efficient algorithm for checking anagrams is to use `qsort` to sort both arrays, then a simple string matcher to compare them. This will have cost `O(mnlog(m+n))`, as opposed to `O(m^2 n^2)`, awith the current algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You need to split every line you read by `fgets` (as you did) in to two strings, and pass them to your `find_anagram` function. You can do that using  [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

```
int main()
{
  int flag;
  char buf[1000];
  FILE *ptr_file;

  //Check file existence

  //Open the file for reading

  while (fgets (buf, 1000, ptr_file) != NULL)
    {
      char *array1 = strtok(buf, "#");
      char *array2 = strtok(NULL, "\n");

      flag = find_anagram (array1, array2);

      //Check flag value to print your message
    }

  return 0;
}

//put your find_anagram function
```

Don't forget to `#include <string.h>` to use `strtok()`.